# Configuring a Z-Wave Controller

Tags: windows, linux, usb, home-automation

I'm looking for a simple piece of software (for PC or Linux) which can interface with a Z-Wave USB controller. All it needs to do is list the nodes that are connected to that device, and allow for adding/removing nodes and resetting the device.

I am not looking for a home-automation software solution, just a simple Z-Wave Mesh Network overviewer. In fact, even if it were read-only (no support for adding / removing nodes), it would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest taking a look at the work being done on [OpenZWave](http://www.openzwave.com/) - it looks like there are only source code distributions but you should be able to either find what you need or possibly build something suitable.

Features:

- Developed in C++
- Dotnet wrapper for Windows
- Portable to most Linux, Mac OSX and Windows Platforms
- Works with the multiple [ZWave Controllers](https://code.google.com/p/open-zwave/wiki/Controller_Compatibility_List)
- ZWave Protocol is abstracted away hiding a lot of the complexity
- Works with most switches, dimmers, thermostats, energy monitors, motion sensors, appliance modules,key fobs, door/window sensors, etc.
- Security related devices are work in progress
- Reverse Engineered the ZWave Protocol
- Easy to add support for new devices
- Fully Documented Code Base
- Includes simple examples to demonstrate how to interface to the code
- [Python](http://python.org) wrappers available e.g. [here](https://code.google.com/p/python-openzwave/).

Comment: This looks like a great library, and it supports my controller (Aeon Z-Stick), but I was hoping to find something with a ready-to-go mesh network overview gui (or command-line output). i don't see any such offerings from the OpenZWave library, and if I can't find another solution, I'll use this library to write a quick and dirty version of the tool i'm looking for. thank you.

Comment: If you use the python wrappers it should be only a dozen or so lines to make a command line tool & slightly more to add a basic GUI with something like wxPython.